# Testcafe - How to write testcafe selector to identify element with class contains

Tags: testing, automated-tests, selector, e2e-testing, testcafe

I need to write the location of an element in page which has just the tag name and only 1 attribute - class and the class value has number characters which is dynamic so I have to use contains to specify the element.

Could not traverse from parent node as it is a list with similar parent name.

Any Suggestions please??

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Selector.withAttribute](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/test-api/selector/withattribute.html) method.

For example, the following code finds an input with an attribute, which name ends with 'testId' and clicks on it.

```
await t.click(Selector('input').withAttribute(/.*testid/);
```

Comment: my question is, whether we have option like xpath where we give contains to find matching element, example : //*[contains(text(),'Google')]

Comment: if you need to search by element's text, try the [Selector.withText()](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/test-api/selector/withtext.html)  method.